Does ODI has RunTime column Propagation (DataStage) or Copy Data (ADF) Equivalent?
I am new to ODI.  I am familiar with DataStage and Azure Data Factory.  I have to migrate 200+ Tables (All tables have different DDL).  The Data is available in the form of Text files and needs to be loaded to Oracle.
In DataStage, we can use RCP to pass the table names and have one Job/Mapping to read the files and load the tables.
In ADF, using a Copy Data and for each loop, we can load the data.
Is there a similar concept in ODI?
The Intent is to have one mapping and ability to pass the table name and filename as variables and get the data loaded (without column Definitions)
